# Measuring Apache request processing times

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, performance

I want to measure performance of my server. The architecture is Apache2 talking to Tomcat over mod_jk. Requests are over HTTPS with mutual authentication. The client does not reuse connections, therefore I believe a new SSL session is established for each transaction.

If I configure Apache to log `%D` in [mod_log_config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html), does that duration include the time spent doing SSL, including the TLS handshake? If not, how do I measure that part of the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing some stress test with [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) for an end to end test. Also enable some monitoring options in Tomcat like jmxremote.

Comment: Yes, of course I can measure the transaction on the client cide, but I want to eliminate the network overhead. And `%D` already gives more accurate numbers than measuring inside Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly no,

Apache Httpd (tested on 2.2) does not include the time of the TLS handshake, which means he also doesn't include the TCP handshake either.

The Tomcat %D (tested on version 8) behaves the same as Apache Httpd, which is unfortunate for us as well.

This means the only simple way of monitoring in production the impact of TLS, is from the client side.

If you just need to check session reuse once, you can also use Wireshark on the client or server side.